# R: how to plot data from two separate data.frames

Tags: r, plot, melt

```
dat.x <- data.frame(var1 = 1, var2 = 1.5, var3 = 3)
dat.y <- data.frame(var1 = 3, var2 = 1.5, var3 = 3)

plot(dat.x$var1, dat.y$var1, col = "red", xlim = c(0.6, 3.5), ylim = c(0, 4), xlab = "x", ylab = 'y')
points(dat.x$var2, dat.y$var2, col = "blue")
points(dat.x$var3, dat.y$var3, col = "green")
```

[image]

I have two data.frames, `dat.x` and `dat.y`, that contain the x and y coordinates of 3 observations. Is there a quick way to plot these points? Perhaps using `melt` from the reshape2 package to organize the 2 data.frames into a single one?

Comment: You can create a new data frame by combining your two data frames. Use this new frame to plot your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dat.x <- data.frame(var1 = 1, var2 = 1.5, var3 = 3)
dat.y <- data.frame(var1 = 3, var2 = 1.5, var3 = 3)

dat.z <- matrix(data = c(dat.x, dat.y), nrow = 3, ncol = 2)
dat.z <- as.data.frame(dat.z, row.names = c("var1", "var2", "var3"))

plot(dat.z)
```